# Display external javascript content as text in html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display javascript code that is linked to the html page using a script tag as text on the same html page (and also syntax highlighted) as a tool for users to see the underlying javascript code.

Eventually I also want to display the html and css file contents as a learning tool so users can see all the components in a user-friendly manner on the same page (at the bottom in a tab control).

The other requirement is that the files are local and not stored on a web server. And last but not least I would like to keep this as simple as possible (no jQuery, no additional javascript if possible).

I have tried a couple of approaches without much success:

- using HTML5 import and AJAX, encountered CORS and local file access
  errors
- embed HTML5 tag, encountered prompt to execute javascript, not good
- iframe tag , encountered prompt to execute javascript, not good

I am looking for simple and working solutions, I have searched quite a bit, but it is difficult to find something where you want to "convert" javascript into plain text and display it on an HTML page.

Comment: You could escape the special characters with PHP if that's available

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the `src` attribute from the script element and loading the file content via a separate HTTP call is probably the most feasible solution.

An example for the lodash source code, using jQuery:

```js
var src = $('#lodash').attr('src');

$.get(src, undefined, function(data) {
  $('#content').text(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script id='lodash' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.js'></script>

<pre id='content'></pre>
```